# How to set malloc-lib in mysql 5.7 in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqld-safe

I recently installed jemmaloc 3.6.0-11 using `apt-get install libjemalloc1` on my ubuntu server 18.04

The installation were successfull, but when I check using

```
pt-mysql-summary | grep -A5 -i "memory management"
```

I get

```
    Memory management library 
    jemalloc is not enabled in mysql config 
for process with id 89539 
    The End
```

How I can do this ?

I am using Mysql 5.7.26

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a bit more to get this to work.  This worked for me.  First the problem:

Starting in Ubuntu 18.04, Percona / MySQL are configured thru systemd
This means setting malloc-lib= in my.cnf no longer works!  It also no longer works "out of the box" (at least not for me).

So how do we get this to work?

1. Create an override.conf file to load jemalloc.  This is done using systemd controls.

   `sudo systemctl edit mysql`
2. This will pop up an editor.  Unless this has been done before, odds are this will be a blank new file. Enter this in:

   [Service]

   Environment="LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1"
3. Then `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` which loads the override.conf
4. Then `sudo systemctl restart mysql` which restarts the server

Resources:

- The heavy lifting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/using-systemd.html
- Percona blog article: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/01/03/enabling-and-disabling-jemalloc-on-percona-server/

The instructions on how to verify the jemalloc is actually being used are key.

Comment: Seems the deb package systemd.service files are lagging behind the rpm packages.  If you use rpm packages, you can put "LD_PRELOAD=...." in /etc/sysconfig/mysql, however the deb systemd.service file is missing the EnvironmentFile directive.  Guess I'll file an enhancement request for that!

Comment: I filed enhancement request: MySQL Bug #101363 Ubuntu systemd service file missing EnvironmentFile directive

Answer (score 0):

found it

it turned out I need to add a line 
Environment=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1

in /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service

what a headache hahaha